# HTML load number of input fields the user enters on button click

Tags: javascript, html

i am making a form which will be used to create a table in database, (same thing that we do in PHPMyadmin, i am just giving it a UI)
i have these input fields

```
<div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="" style="">

          <div class="col-md-3">
           <strong>Table name</strong> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="table_name" required>
                <br>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <strong>Number of Columns</strong> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="table_column" required>
                </div>       
        </form>
         <div class="col-md-1">
                <br>
                <button type="" class='btn btn-primary load_table' >Create </button>
                </div>
                </div>
```

when create button is pressed, it goes into this

```
    $(".load_table").click(function()
  {

        var name = document.getElementsByName('table_name')[0].value;
        var columns = document.getElementsByName('table_column')[0].value;
        document.getElementById("form").style.visibility = 'visible';

    });
```

and this form below with `id=form` , which is initially hidden, is set to be visible.

```
 <form method="post" class="form-horizontal" id="form" action="" style="visibility:hidden">   


    <div class="col-md-3">

        <strong>Name</strong> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="city">
        <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <strong>Type</strong> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="country">
        <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <strong>Length/value</strong> <input type="text" class="form-control" name="region_id">
        <br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
        <br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary form-control" id="button1" name="insert" value="insert">Submit</button>
      </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

my aim is to dynamically generete the number user enters as `number of columns` as total number of columns as it is done on phpmyadmin create table screen. whats the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do some thing like this..

```js
var columnCount=3;//get Your column Count
for(i=1;i <= columnCount ;i++)
  {
  document.getElementById('form').innerHTML+=getFormColumn(i);
  if(i==columnCount)
  {
  document.getElementById('form').innerHTML+="<input type='submit' value='Create Table'>";
   } 
  }


function getFormColumn(i)
{
 return "<label id='name_"+i+"'>Name</label><input type='text' name='name[]'><label id='name_"+i+"'>Type</label><input type='text' name='type[]'><br/>";
}
```

```html
<form id='form' action='YourUrl' method='post'>

</form>
```